# Highlighting failed field in selenium webdriver during runtime

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to highlight a failed field using selenium webdriver during run time. Can anyone tell me the code for that?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What do you mean by "failed field"?

Comment: A field where execution stops,

Comment: What exception? What code are you executing? Provide an example, better reproducable, and the desired output.

Comment: Like a field for phone number I coded it as it will accept 11 digits. But it in reality it will accept only 10 digits. So in that case the execution will stop at the field before the phon enumber field. So in that case I want to highlight the phonenumber field.

Comment: In this state the question is too broad. Please show the code you have so far with the link, or the HTML code of the place where this example "phonenumber" is.

Comment: <input tabindex="0" type="tel" name="telNr" required="" ng-pattern="/^\d{8}?$/" tooltip="" r-floating-label="Mobiltelefon" data-error="Verdi mangler" ng-model="formData.telNr" placeholder="Mobiltelefon" class="ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid-required non-empty ng-valid ng-valid-pattern ng-touched" id="1bmp">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update html elements CSS at runtime using little Javascript.

Following method would add red border to element:

```
// Method to Highlight Element
public static void highLightElement(Webdriver webdriver, WebElement element) throws InterruptedException {
    JavascriptExecutor driver = (JavascriptExecutor) webdriver;
    driver.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style',arguments[1]);", element, "border: 2px solid red;");
}
```